# Recommendation for D&D 4E campaign books?

Tags: dnd-4e, published-adventures, campaign, adventure-path

I'm a guy that's never DMed before but I'm looking at doing so very soon (I will be DMing for about 5 players.) However, due to the amount of free time I have, I won't be able to create many of my own stories for my campaign. So I'm just wondering, which pre-planned campaign books should I buy in order for my campaign to continue running for up to 52 (a session each week for a year) sessions that last 2 hours each?

Thanks heaps.

-EDIT-
I forgot to mention a few things, my bad. I don't mind about the price because I'm planning on D&D to be one of my primary hobbies. My players are casual but they won't mind difficult campaigns. The complexity of the story does not matter too much as long as it doesn't require a lot of time investment in order to be enjoyed. I don't want something like the Silmarillion. I would prefer something that's mostly relevant and/or interesting rather than just added information for the sake of realism and immersion. My players prefer fantasy but not by a significant margin; as long as the story is fun and interesting, they will like it.
The type of campaign we are looking for does not matter much, although, my two youngest players who are also my brothers (12 and 14) would prefer something that has a little more action but again, I don't think it would matter a lot.

Oh and I should add that I'll be playing online (Virtual Tabletop) so the amount of pieces needed will not matter.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You should add some details about your requirements for campaign books (price, complexity, theme, difficulty) so that this question doesn't get closed.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I've updated the post and I'll be continuing to update it if I find that I've missed out anything.

Comment: Great start! I'd also recommend adding the *type* of campaign you're looking for. A dark, gritty survival campaign? A heroic fantasy, sword-and-sorcery style? A game of political intrigue?

Comment: Just edited. Are there any other suggestions? Thanks once again!

Comment: I would suggest removing the system recommendation portion of the question. It should be it's own question if you want it, and needs some significant details of it's own (check the [tag:game-recommendation] tag for more details).

Comment: @spyingspy Here is the thing: there are a _lot_ of D&D 4e adventure books. We do recommendations only in the provision you provide criteria which narrows down the possibilities such that there can exist an objectively judgeable correct/best answer. Nothing in this question narrows the list down from "any of them." Please see [our rules for game recommendation questions](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1071) (our general 'shopping advice' category). We don't usually apply stringent rules to _other_ kinds of questions, but without these rules this type of question would be banned entirely.

Comment: Also, I have rolled back your edit about being open to suggestions for another ruleset. There are literally _thousands_ of RPGs in existence for all kinds of games, so just asking for one has the same problems: we could just provide you with any of them. Hop on [DriveThruRPG](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/) or [RPGGeek](http://rpggeek.com/) to see what's available.

Comment: Just to be sure: are you looking for a campaign book so that you have a world and can make your own stories, or are you looking for an adventure book, so you have the complete story already made? Your title suggests the first, but from your question I take the latter.

Comment: Worth noting that 2 hours is a very short for a 4e session; using default rules, I've had single combats that lasted longer than 2 hours. You may want to do the trick of halving monster HP and multiplying their damage by 1.5 or 2.